# Why am I getting a java.lang.ClassCastException in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, casting, classcastexception

I wrote this sample code that I extracted from a library that I'm making because it is causing a `java.lang.ClassCastException` and I don't understand why. Here's the code:

```kotlin
interface Event

data class Update(val message: Message?)
open class Message(open val text: String?)
data class TextMessage(override val text: String) : Message(text = text)

class MessageReceiveEvent(
    val message: Message,
) : Event

class TextMessageReceiveEvent(
    val message: TextMessage,
) : Event

fun handleUpdate(update: Update): Event {
    if (update.message != null) {
        if (update.message.text != null) return TextMessageReceiveEvent(update.message as TextMessage)
        return MessageReceiveEvent(update.message)
    }
    error("Update message is null.")
}

handleUpdate(
    Update(
        message = Message(
            text = "Text" // if this is null, the program successfully runs.
        )
    )
).let {
    if (it is MessageReceiveEvent) println("Message without text.")
    if (it is TextMessageReceiveEvent) println("Message with text.")
}
```

Comment: Just follow the stack trace and you'll find the cause of the problem.

Comment: @k314159 yeah that's what I did and I got a java.lang.ClassCastException at `TextMessageReceiveEvent(update.message as TextMessage)`. I'm trying to understand *why* I got that exception when performing the cast.

Comment: Do you think it's reasonable to assume that `update.message` is a `TextMessage` just because it contains a non-null text?

Comment: @k314159 yes, I do.

Comment: Why? You can see that you've created a Message containing non-null text which is _not_ a TextMessage.

Answer (score 1):

This code is not correct:

```kotlin
if (update.message.text != null)
    return TextMessageReceiveEvent(update.message as TextMessage)
return MessageReceiveEvent(update.message)
```

You are trying to cast `update.message` as a `TextMessage`, but nothing guarantees that it is of this type. The fact that `TextMessage` happens to be very similar to `Message` apart from the nullability of the `text` property doesn't mean that every `Message` with non-null text is actually an instance of `TextMessage`.

You would have to actually confirm that with `update.message is TextMessage`.

Comment: Ah, okay, I understand! Every `TextMessage` is a `Message` but not every `Message` is a `TextMessage`. However, what are my options to convert a `Message` to a `TextMessage`? I can write a `Message.toTextMessage()` method but the problem I have with this is that in the API I'm making, a `Message` has a lot of parameters: https://pastebin.com/YwaKw5A0